# Почему после запуска нечего не происходит?

Tags: python

Вот сервер:

```
import json

from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

stats = {
    'attempts': 0,
    'success':0,
}

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return f'Hello, user! stats={stats}'

@app.route('/auth', methods=['POST'])
def auth():
    stats['attempts'] += 1

    data = request.json
    login = data['login']
    password = data['password']
    print(login, password)

    with open('users.json') as users_file:
        users = json.load(users_file)


    if login in users and users[login] == password:
        status_code = 200
        stats['success'] += 1
    else:
        status_code = 401

    return Response(status=status_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run
```

Comment: А как Вы запускаете?

Comment: Потому что скобки нужны: app.run()

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `app.run` - это метода класса `app`.
Если вывести в консоль что он возвращает, то получим:

`<bound method Flask.run of <Flask '2'>>`

А чтобы запустить сервер, нужно вызвать этот метод. Для этого нужно добавить скобки
`app.run()`